# BeautifulSoup, Python 3.3: UnicodeEncodeError for a string concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am a novice Python programmer converting a script that ran on Python 2.7 to Python 3.3. I've fixed a bunch of problems (urllib2 etc) and now Im stuck on this one:

```
f.write(  soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"topictitle"})[x3].string.strip(' \t\n\r')  + ',' +
                                      inx + ',' +
                                      treadid + ',' +
                                      sid + ',' +
                                      link2.get('href') 
                                      + ',' 
                                      + "http://civicfbthailand.com/forum/" 
                                      + lnk.encode('utf-8')
                                      + '\n'
                                      )
```

Which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "civicforum.py", line 73, in <module>
   + '\n'
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Line 73 is the one listed "+ '\n'" but I dont understand why this string cannot be concatenated, or the behaviour difference between P27 and P33.
Any enlightenment appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `.encode('utf-8')` part of `lnk.encode('utf-8')` in your code. The `.encode()` method is used in Python 2.8 to hack around the fact that python2 strings are ASCII whereas Python3 strings are unicode, and thus that kind of hack is not necessary anymore… And not working ;-)

```
f.write(  soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"topictitle"})[x3].string.strip(' \t\n\r')  + ',' +
                                      inx + ',' +
                                      treadid + ',' +
                                      sid + ',' +
                                      link2.get('href') 
                                      + ',' 
                                      + "http://civicfbthailand.com/forum/" 
                                      + lnk
                                      + '\n'
                                      )
```